# Not able to start apache2 in ubuntu

Tags: terminal, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

Error i get is:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

After running command **systemctl status apache2.service** i get :

```
    apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-08 13:27:50 IST; 2min 12
  Process: 12058 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=127)

May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal apachectl[12058]: /usr/sbin/apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/ap
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal apachectl[12058]: Action 'start' failed.
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal apachectl[12058]: The Apache error log may have more inf
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, cod
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

After running **journalctl -xe** i get:

```
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal sudo[12024]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for 
May 08 13:27:50 kaushal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
May 08 13:27:53 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:27:54 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:27:55 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:27:56 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:28:21 kaushal /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2772]: (EE) client bug: time
May 08 13:28:26 kaushal kernel: psmouse serio4: Touchpad at isa0060/serio4/input
May 08 13:28:26 kaushal kernel: psmouse serio4: Touchpad at isa0060/serio4/input
May 08 13:28:36 kaushal kernel: psmouse serio4: Touchpad at isa0060/serio4/input
May 08 13:28:36 kaushal kernel: psmouse serio4: Touchpad at isa0060/serio4/input
May 08 13:29:53 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:29:54 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:29:55 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
May 08 13:29:56 kaushal kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=00:08:ca:f0:27:04
lines 1328-1350/1350 (END)
```